# Ping hostname works but nslookup to hostname doesn't

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, nslookup

I have a Windows 2008 standard server which can ping by hostname and give me the proper IP address back however if I try to do an nslookup on the hostname I receive:

```
server: nmgdc1.nmg.local
Address 192.168.1.10
DNS request timed out. timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out. timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to nmgdc1.nmg.local timed-out
```

I can get to the website fine through a web browser and can do a successful nslookup from a different client. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

As people have been pointing out your DNS server on 192.168.1.10 is not setup correctly or is not the right DNS server.

However the name can still be resolved by windows, probably using what is called [NetBIOS over TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP) that works like an automatic DNS server system with auto server discovery on a LAN but doesn't scale well and is a bit hit and miss on it actually working.

Answer (score 0):

Check the DNS Server entries on the problematic host. Chances are, it's not using the same DNS server as everything else that's working correctly.

Comment: I have 1 server and 3 computers at this location and none of them can do an nslookup on the website however from some of my other clients that I manage I can nslookup fine... the server nmgdc1 is my actual DNS server...

Answer (score 0):

If none of the machines on you LAN can complete a nslookup, then it's likely your local DNS can't resolve the hostname properly. It could be an issue with your DNS server, or with just the records for that host.

I would try to nslookup other local hosts, to see if the LAN DNS is functioning. You could also try to nslookup the hostname in question on a public DNS i.e. `nslookup targetHost 208.67.222.222` (openDNS), though it sounds like public resolution is working fine.

Comment: If i do a nslookup targethost 208.67.222.222 than I get the proper IPs back. If I try to a local IP address on the network I get: Server: nmgdc1.nmg.local Address: 192.168.1.10 | *** nmgdc1.nmg.local can't find 192.168.1.150: Non-existent domain.

Comment: Another thing I found is for some reason the server keeps adding a forwarder of 10.100.1.10 even though my ip address is 192.168.1.10. I deleted the forwarder and it seems to re-add itself some how...

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959340.aspx) is from the Windows 2000 TechNet, but the principles and actions should still apply. It's got great troubleshooting and workflow steps to help you identify DNS resolution issues. Keep in mind, nslookup is kind've a PITA if reverse zones aren't established.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your DNS server is not properly set up on the .10 address. My guess is that your TCP/IP stack is using multiple DNS servers and one of them has pointed to the outside world. Go back and reconfigure your .10 address to your outside DNS servers.